# Getting working directory from app when running in simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, directory, working-directory

I want to get the current working directory (application directory) of an app in the simulator. I.e. the folder where the app can store its files when currently running.

One can [right-click on the project in Xamarin Studio and select Open Containing Folder](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/), but that shows only what in the app package is, which will be delivered to the user/app store - not the current created files.

Currently I'm doing this

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
```

and I get something like

> /Users/my-user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9F56EA45-A415-4841-A675-1AC5B7890BD2/data/Containers/Data/Application/A4EE9A21-49E6-474A-AF50-F78135031CD4/Documents

but is there a faster way like the right click above?

Comment: Not at the moment. It also could be that the path changes, mainly the guid, will change.

Answer (score 0):

Get the array of files from current document directory.

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
```

now get your file from the docsDir array.

```
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xyz.db"]];
```